# Adding a cool down to a javascript key press

Tags: javascript, jquery, keycode

I have a Jquery problem today using key Codes, my code dumb below

```
$(function() {
    var distance = 0;
    $('.right').click(function() {
        distance -= 100;
        $('#container').css('transform', 'translateX(' + distance + '%)')
        console.log(distance);
    });
    $('.left').click(function() {
        distance += 100;
        $('#container').css('transform', 'translateX(' + distance + '%);')
        console.log(distance);
    });

    $(window).keypress(function (e) {
      var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
    if(code == 13) {
       $('.right').trigger('click')
    }
    if(code == 9) {
       $('.right').trigger('click')
    }
    if(code == 32) {
       $('.right').trigger('click')
    }
    if(code == 39) {
       $('.right').trigger('click')
    }
    });
});
```

So I am having some trouble making the arrow key presses work.

```
if(code == 32) {
    $('.right').trigger('click')
}
if(code == 39) {
    $('.right').trigger('click')
}
```

Not only that but I can't seem to figure out a way to put a delay on it (1s) so it doesn't add a few hundred to the distance var when I only want it to do it once, so lets say instead of delay, a cool down.

### UPDATE

While I'm at it I would like to ask if anyone has any solutions to putting a maximum and miniumum amount on

```
var distance = 0;
```

Comment: Is it a cool down that applies to every function on that applies to every key simultaneously or is it that key code 13 can't be called for 1s but key code 39 can still be called within that time?

Comment: @SteveBotello every key but then it could also be implemented into the click events above, which I'm also chucking on buttons in the webpage. That code there is basically a animation from page to page but I also want the user to be able to use keys.

Answer (score 2):

Look at `debounce` and `throttle` mechanisms described [here](https://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-throttling-and-debouncing/). It should help you in achieving the delay/cool down.

Comment: Thank you for that, it looks like that could really help me, just having trouble figuring out a way to implement that into my situation, I'll keep researching it :)